# Mann Whitney U test

Tags: r

I want to create a function that can calculate the U value of the function in R and calculates the p-value using exact distribution with 10000 replications .
My R function

```
U<-function(x,y){
 n1<-length(x)
n2<-length(y)
d<-n1+n2
}
```

But I do no know the procedure that will calculate the Mann Whitney U test.Here,x and y are two differen and independent sample.

Comment: Why don't you use the dedicated function of R: `wilcox.test()` ?

Comment: I can use but I am asked to form a function by first combining the vector x and y and then using the rank calculate the U value for x.

Comment: is this a homework problem?  If so, please add the self study tag